# Is there a setting in Outlook that enables encryption for **some** messages?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, encryption

The [support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Encrypt-e-mail-messages-84d7e382-5f76-4d71-8705-324489b710a2) describes how to encrypt **one** message and how to encrypt **all** messages.

However, I'd like to encrypt **some** messages, based on certain conditions (for example keywords, attachments, attachment names, ...).

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have the system in place to digitally sign and/or encrypt your message currently in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this automatically, sorry. You can either enable encryption for all outgoing messages or encrypt each message manually.